# executing keras CNN models keeps crashing my computer

Tags: r, tensorflow, keras, rstudio

I'm trying to get into deep learning with R. Using various blogs online I'm trying to test their code and see how they actually work. With keras, I'm not sure why but everytime I run a modelfunction It keeps crashing. 
I'm sorry if I haven't provided enough information. I'm running an AMD GPU and CPU
 Example code section

```
history <- model %>% fit_generator(
  train_generator,
  steps_per_epoch = 100,
  epochs = 100,
  validation_data = validation_generator,
  validation_steps = 50,
)
use_multiprocessing=False
```

an also

```
hist <- model %>% fit_generator(
  # training data
  train_image_array_gen,

  # epochs
  steps_per_epoch = as.integer(train_samples / batch_size), 
  epochs = epochs, 

  # validation data
  validation_data = valid_image_array_gen,
  validation_steps = as.integer(valid_samples / batch_size),

  # print progress
  verbose = 2,
  callbacks = list(
    # save best model after every epoch
    callback_model_checkpoint("C:/Users/My Account/Desktop/fruits_checkpoints.h5", save_best_only = TRUE),

  )
```

Comment: can you post the error message ?

Comment: hi sorry for the delay, the Rstudio program just closes and says my program

Comment: @mctosh Does it display any message related to memory ? Is it the gui which crashes ?

Comment: Yeah sorry, the GUI just instantly crashes specifically when I use this block too model %>% compile(
  loss = 'binary_crossentropy',
  optimizer = "adam",
  metrics = c('accuracy')
)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the problem is with Keras using `tensorflow-gpu`. Try running the model after installing `tensorflow` cpu version. Since, you are using AMD gpu, you may not be able to use the tensorflow gpu version with cudnn libraries.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I'll try doing that today